# How to add pagination in subcategory collection in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, category, pagination

I have written following code to display subcategories

```
    <ul class="">
  <?php
$_categories=$this->getCurrentChildCategories();
if($_categories->count()):
$categorycount = 0;
foreach ($_categories as $_category):
if($_category->getIsActive()):
$cur_category=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId());
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$layer->setCurrentCategory($cur_category);
$catName = $this->getCurrentCategory()->getName();
?>
  <li class="">
    <div class="">
      <div class="">
        <div class=""> <a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>" class="">
          <?php
                    $imageUrl = Mage::getBaseDir('media')."/"."catalog"."/"."category"."/".$this->getCurrentCategory()->getThumbnail();

                    $imageResized = Mage::getBaseDir('media')."/"."catalog"."/"."category"."/"."resize/".$this->getCurrentCategory()->getThumbnail();


                    if (!file_exists($imageResized) && file_exists($imageUrl)) 
                    {

                    $imageObj = new Varien_Image($imageUrl);
                    $imageObj->constrainOnly(TRUE);
                    $imageObj->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);
                    $imageObj->keepFrame(FALSE);
                    $imageObj->quality(100);
                    $imageObj->resize(270, 270);
                    $imageObj->save($imageResized);
                    }
                    ?>
          <span class=""><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/resize/'.$this->getCurrentCategory()->getThumbnail(); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"/></span> </a> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <div class="">
          <div class=""> <a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <?php
endif;

endforeach;
endif;
?>
</ul>
```

I want to add pagination in this page, i have tried solutions like following but it does not worked either

```
parent::_prepareLayout();
$pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
    $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(15=>15));
    $pager->setCollection($_categories);

    $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
```

Can anyone have any idea on how to add pagination in subcategory listing page?

Please guide me as i am new to magento development.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Step1: Create IndexController

```
<?php
class Tbi_Collection_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();    
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

> Step2: Create Layout xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <collection_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <Tbi type="collection/collection" name="product_list" template="collection/collection.phtml">
            </block>
        </reference>
    </collection_index_index>
</layout>
```

> Step3: Block in the local/block/Collection.php

```
<?php
class Tbi_Collection_Block_Collection extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $parent_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
        if($this->getRequest()->getParam('category_id',false)){
            $parent_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('category_id');
        }
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('parent_id',$parent_id);
        $collection->addIsActiveFilter();
        $collection->addNameToResult();
        $collection->addUrlRewriteToResult();
        //$collection->setLoadProductCount(true);
        $this->setCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $parent_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
        if($this->getRequest()->getParam('category_id',false)){
            $parent_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('category_id');
        }
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parent_id);

        if ($headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')) {
            if ($title = $category->getMetaTitle()) {
                $headBlock->setTitle($title);
            }
            if ($description = $category->getMetaDescription()) {
                $headBlock->setDescription($description);
            }
            if ($keywords = $category->getMetaKeywords()) {
                $headBlock->setKeywords($keywords);
            }
        }
        $this->setTitle($category->getName());


        $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();

        // called prepare sortable parameters
        $collection = $this->getCollection();

        // use sortable parameters
        if ($orders = $this->getAvailableOrders()) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
        $toolbar->setCollection($collection);

        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
        return $this;
    }
    public function getDefaultDirection(){
        return 'asc';
    }
    public function getAvailableOrders(){
        return array('name'=> 'Name','position'=>'Position','children_count'=>'Sub Category Count');
    }
    public function getSortBy(){
        return 'name';
    }
    public function getToolbarBlock()
    {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('collection/toolbar', microtime());
        return $block;
    }
    public function getMode()
    {
        return $this->getChild('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
    }

    public function getToolbarHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
    }
}
```

> Create the block class ‘collection/toolbar’ which is used in the above Class

```
<?php
class Tbi_Collection_Block_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar{
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        $pagerBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager');

        if ($pagerBlock instanceof Varien_Object) {

            /* @var $pagerBlock Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager */
            $pagerBlock->setAvailableLimit($this->getAvailableLimit());

            $pagerBlock->setUseContainer(false)
            ->setShowPerPage(false)
            ->setShowAmounts(false)
            ->setLimitVarName($this->getLimitVarName())
            ->setPageVarName($this->getPageVarName())
            ->setLimit($this->getLimit())
            ->setCollection($this->getCollection());
            return $pagerBlock->toHtml();
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

> Step4: .phtml Files

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php $collection = $this->getCollection(); ?>
<div class="page-title">
    <h1><?php echo $this->__($this->getTitle()) ?></h1>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml(); ?>
<?php if($collection->getSize()): ?>

    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <!-- List Model -->
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($collection as $category):
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId()); ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($collection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($category->getName()); ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $category->getImageUrl() ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($category->getName()); ?>" /></a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($category->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $category->getName(); ?></a></h2>
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $category->getDescription(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php if($category->getChildrenCount()){ ?>
                    <div>
                        <a href='<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/*',array('category_id'=>$category->getId()))?>'>View Sub Category</a>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>
    <?php else: ?>

    <!-- Grid Mode -->

    <?php $_collectionSize = $collection->count() ?>
    <?php
        $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount();
        if(!$_columnCount){
            $_columnCount = 3;
        }
    ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($collection as $category):
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
    ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid">
        <?php endif ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($category->getName()); ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $category->getImageUrl() ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($category->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a></h2>
                <?php if($category->getChildrenCount()){ ?>
                <div>
                    <a href='<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/*',array('category_id'=>$category->getId()))?>'>View Sub Category</a>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </li>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('The collection is empty.'); ?></p>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Thank You for your reply, Can you please post the path and name of this files (like for indexController, app/code/indexController.php). as i am not able to define its path

Comment: Tbi_Collection_IndexController, means Tbi/Colection/IndexController.php, the classes themselves defines the path name, refer to other core files of magento and you will understand

Comment: Thank You..!! I got it, it will app/code/local/Tbi/Collection/IndexController.php

Comment: I have created these files 1. `app/code/local/Tbi/Collection/IndexController.php` 2. `app/code/local/Tbi/Collection/Block/Collection.php` 3. `app/code/local/Tbi/Collection/Block/Toolbar.php` 4. `app\design\frontend\default\default\template\collection\collection.phtml` 5. `app\design\frontend\default\default\layout\collection.xml` then created static block with this code `{{block type="collection/collection" template="collection/collection.phtml"}}` and selected that static block in category, but i'm getting blank page

Comment: Please help, did i missed anything?

Comment: ok so you have copied code from this url http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-collection-paging and pasted it here